# What are the boundary conditions for the electron in a hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

From what I understand, the wave equation for an electron can be constructed using the "particle in a box" model in three dimensions. However, what would be the boundary conditions in this case? In other words, what are the potential energy barriers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the potential varies smoothly so there are no "barriers" so to speak. (as far as I'm aware there are no discontinuous potentials in reality)

Examples of boundary conditions in the case of the hydrogen atom would be that the radial wavefunction should go to zero at the origin and at infinity, and that the angular wavefunction should be periodic with period $2 \pi$.

Comment: A minor comment: the probability should vanish at the origin, the wave function not necessarily. It depends on the Jacobian.

Comment: I'm not sure about that detail, can you explain what you mean by this (I am interested in an example where this isn't true). Most sources I have seen set the radial wavefunction to zero at the origin.

Comment: Look for example at the wavefunction of the 1s orbital $\psi_{100}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a_0^{\frac{3}{2}}}e^{-\frac{r}{a_0}}$. It doesn't vanish at the origin.

Comment: If you meant $rR(r)$ for the radial wavefunction then you are correct of course. It indeed includes the jacobian.

Comment: I  think it is sufficient that $\psi \in L^2$ for this contains implicitly the behavior at infinity.